# How to inflate custom layout in details fragment leanback

Tags: android, leanback

I need to inflate/add a full width custom layout after DetailOverviewRow but there is no way and you can only add a ListRow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer:

First i need to create a class that extends `RowPresenter` and inflate my view into that, also create a class that extends `Row` and put my data into that.

`FullWidthPresenter`:

```
class FullWidthPresenter : RowPresenter() {

    override fun createRowViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.fullwidth_row,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }
}
```

And `CustomRow`:

```
class CustomRow(val item: String) : Row()
```

In use:

```
val selector = ClassPresenterSelector().apply {

        FullWidthRowPresenter().also {
           addClassPresenter(CustomRow::class.java, it)
        }
      
        val rowsAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(selector)

        val customRow = CustomRow("Media Item Details")
        rowsAdapter.add(customRow)
        adapter = rowsAdapter
}
```

Comment: can you please share how you used it? also, the purpose for this extra row is so when you press the down d-pad, it will scroll down to that view?

Comment: 1- You only create an instance of FullWidthPresenter and if you are using ClassPreseneterSelector add a new class presenter with CustomRow. 
2- Create an instance of CustomRow and add this in your arrayObjectAdapter.